# Python requests to input value for search button

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I have below html where I need to input some text in value. I am trying with below python code using requests module, however it is not working as expected. Can someone please help.

Original html:

```html
<div class="O8ZS_U">
  <input autocomplete="off" class="LM6RPg" name="q" placeholder="Search for products, brands and more" title="Search for products, brands and more" type="text" value=""/>
</div>
```

Expected html to post:

```html
<div class="O8ZS_U">
 <input autocomplete="off" class="LM6RPg" name="q" placeholder="Search for products, brands and more" title="Search for products, brands and more" type="text" value="mobiles"/>
</div>
```

Python code:

```py
import requests
r=requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/", verify=False)
search=r.find('input' , value="")
search="mobile"
form={"" : search}
mobile=requests.post("https://www.flipkart.com/", data=form, verify=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = str(input("Which Product You Would Like To Search For\n> "))

params = {
    'q': query,
    'otracker': 'search',
    'otracker1': 'search',
    'marketplace': 'FLIPKART',
    'as-show': 'on',
    'as': 'off'
}

r = requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search", params=params)
print(r.url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# print(soup.prettify())
```