# Beautiful Soup scraping: Shape of data frame is incorrect

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am getting an error when creating a Pandas data frame with these datasets obtained with BeautifulSoup web scraping code. I am new to Python. [Code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uL3T.png)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


products = []
prices = []
ratings = []

html = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/pr?sid=6bo,b5g&otracker=categorytree&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_12950206-1c2a-4419-a79b-f7f7ee1c9b03_1_372UD5BXDFYS_MC.34WHNYFH5V2Y&otracker=hp_rich_navigation_13_1.navigationCard.RICH_NAVIGATION_Electronics~Laptop%2Band%2BDesktop_34WHNYFH5V2Y&otracker1=hp_rich_navigation_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_NA_NAV_EXPANDABLE_navigationCard_cc_13_L1_view-all&cid=34WHNYFH5V2Y').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

products = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'_4rR01T'})
print(products.text)


for a in soup.find_all('a',href=True, attrs={'class':'_1fQZEK'}):
    name = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_4rR01T'})
    price = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_30jeq3 _1_WHN1'})
    rating = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_3LWZlK'})
    
    products.append(name.text)
    prices.append(price.text)
    ratings.append(rating.text)
    
    
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product name': products,'Price':prices,'Rating':ratings})
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)`
```

*** ValueError: Shape of passed values is (25, 3), indices imply (24, 3)

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far? Could you please copy-paste your code here? Then we can easily help you! What is the error you get?

Comment: you are reusing products variable in ```products = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'_4rR01T'})
``` which is causing the length of products increase by 1 than others. rename that variable and it will work.

Comment: maybe you would like to check my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60642999/python-requests-to-input-value-for-search-button/60643489#60643489)

Answer (score 0):

if you will print:

```
print(len(products))
print(len(prices))
print(len(ratings))
```

you will get:

```
25
24
24
```

find extra value in products (there is unpacked tag there)

your working code:|

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd


products = []
names = []
prices = []
ratings = []

html = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/pr?sid=6bo,b5g&otracker=categorytree&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_12950206-1c2a-4419-a79b-f7f7ee1c9b03_1_372UD5BXDFYS_MC.34WHNYFH5V2Y&otracker=hp_rich_navigation_13_1.navigationCard.RICH_NAVIGATION_Electronics~Laptop%2Band%2BDesktop_34WHNYFH5V2Y&otracker1=hp_rich_navigation_PINNED_neo%2Fmerchandising_NA_NAV_EXPANDABLE_navigationCard_cc_13_L1_view-all&cid=34WHNYFH5V2Y').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

products = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'_4rR01T'})

for a in soup.find_all('a',href=True, attrs={'class':'_1fQZEK'}):
    name = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_4rR01T'})
    price = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_30jeq3 _1_WHN1'})
    rating = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_3LWZlK'})

    names.append(name.text)
    prices.append(price.text)
    ratings.append(rating.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product name':names, 'Price':prices, 'Rating':ratings})
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

[image: result in jupyter]

Comment: Thank you Igor. I will try this and let you know I go. Appreciate your help friend!

Comment: I am getting this error now. *** ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: why? I ran this code and obtained normal df with 3 columns. see updated image in answer

Comment: I use python - 3.8, pandas - 1.1.4, beautifulsoup4 - 4.4.1